# What is causing my ggplot2 boxplot to turn into skinny lines instead of wide boxes using the width argument?

Tags: r, ggplot2, width, boxplot

I am struggling with boxplots in R studio. I have a data set that looks like this:

| Site | date | Chloride_mgL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2021-06-08 12:00:00 | 29.13800 |
| D | 2021-06-08 12:00:00 | 29.41100 |
| D | 2021-06-15 12:00:00 | 29.92400 |
| E | 2021-06-08 12:00:00 | 29.29100 |
| A | 2021-06-08 12:00:00 | 29.16800 |
| D | 2021-06-22 12:00:00 | 32.79500 |
| C | 2021-06-22 12:00:00 | 30.59200 |

Site is characters, date is POSIXct, and Chloride is numeric. I need to make box plots with date on the x axis and Chloride on the y axis, grouped by date. So, for example, I need a box on 2021-06-08 12:00:00 that is made of all of the Chloride values from all of the sites on that date/time. I can get that made, but for some reason when I make it the boxes are tiny and I need them to be bigger, but the width = function just makes the boxes into skinny lines, and not boxes at all.

This is how I make the box plots:

```
c <- ggplot(sylvan[sylvan$Site %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G") & sylvan$Chloride_mgL > 25, ], aes(x = date, y = Chloride_mgL, group = date)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, color = "dark blue") + theme_minimal() + labs(y ="Chloride (mg/L)")
c
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Great, but I want bigger boxes. So I try to use the width argument:

```
c <- ggplot(sylvan[sylvan$Site %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G") & sylvan$Chloride_mgL > 25, ], aes(x = date, y = Chloride_mgL, group = date)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 2, outlier.shape = NA, color = "dark blue") + theme_minimal() + labs(y ="Chloride (mg/L)")
c
```

And then it turns into this:

[image]

How can I make the boxes wider instead of just turning into skinny little lines? Thanks so much!

Edit: Tried @TarJae solution, and it turned out like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oaztq.jpg)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, with me the (1st and 2nd) boxes are not skinny.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Transform date to datetime: `library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd_hms(date)) %>%` then the boxplots get skinny.

Comment: boxplot width 1 will make the boxes 1 unit wide. With POSIXct in the x axis, 1 unit is 1 second, which is far too narrow for this data. Try width = 60*60*24*5 to make them 5 days wide, for instance. Tricky b/c I see some are closer than that so you'll have overlaps.

Comment: @JonSpring Oh, wow! I had no idea the width was in seconds for POSIXct. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of boxplots with daily data that is in POSIXct:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(date = sample(lubridate::ymd_h(c(
  2023040100, 2023050800, 2023051500, 2023051600)), 100, replace = TRUE),
  mgL = rnorm(100, mean = 29))
```

The default spacing for boxplots on a continuous axis will find a resolution that fits the space.

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, mgL, group = date)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

If we specify width = 1, the boxes will be 1 unit wide, which in POSIXct is 1 second, resulting in boxes that are far too narrow.

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, mgL, group = date)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 1)
```

[image]

Here with 7-day spacing, the first two bars are one week wide, but the last two (which occur one day apart) are squeezed together with narrower bars.

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, mgL, group = date)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 60*60*24*7)
```

[image]

Or we could convert the x axis to Date, where one unit is a day. With width 1, the last two bars will be lined up with no space between them. Any wider and ggplot will squeeze the overlapping ones to avoid an overlap.

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(date), mgL, group = date)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the datetime Class. Try the whole process by leaving date as character the width should work.

##### this explanation is taken directly from @Jon Spring comments:

"boxplot width 1 will make the boxes 1 unit wide. With POSIXct in the x axis, 1 unit is 1 second, which is far too narrow for this data. Try width = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 to make them 5 days wide, for instance. Tricky b/c I see some are closer than that so you'll have overlaps"

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd_hms(date)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Chloride_mgL, group = date)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 2, outlier.shape = NA, color = "dark blue") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(y ="Chloride (mg/L)")
```

[image]

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Chloride_mgL, group = date)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 2, outlier.shape = NA, color = "dark blue") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y = "Chloride (mg/L)")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for answering! So, I tried this: sylvan$date3 <- as.character(sylvan$date)

library(dplyr)
sylvan %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date3, y = Chloride_mgL, group = date3)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 2, outlier.shape = NA, color = "dark blue") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y = "Chloride (mg/L)") and it made the boxes wider, but the x axis is really weird now - let me see if I can add a picture

Comment: Try to toggle `position_dogde(xx)` here   `geom_boxplot(width = 2, outlier.shape = NA, color = "dark blue", position = position_dodge(0.5)) +`

Comment: That made the boxes perfect, thank you so much! One more question though, I wanted the x axis to look like it did in my original pictures (with labels like June, July, etc) but now that I have the x axis as characters, it's displaying every single tick with the entire date/time so it looks super messy and unreadable. Any advice there? (Realizing this might be basic, but I'm still really new to R!)

Comment: One way is to change the angle add:   `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))` . You can use 45 also. Just try out. there are other ways setting breaks etc. or usning `scale_x_date` etc... but this should be a separate question.